# How can form output sent to the same page be used in an iframe?

Tags: php, html, forms, iframe

I have a page containing an iframe and a form targeting the same page (outside the iframe). The form's output seems not to be visible within the iframe. The workaround I use now is that I take the $_POST form output outside the iframe, parse it to variables (with some default values if the form hasn't been sent yet) and then use the variables in the iframe definition. Then in the iframe I parse those values as $_GET. The iframe definition looks like this:

```
echo '<iframe src="foo.php?a='.$a.'&b='.$b.'" >';
```

Is this the optimal solution, or is there anything more elegant available through php?

EDIT: I tried to set form target to the iframe and action to the corresponding page, but doesn't seem to work; I'll try to inspect it further. I'm new to JavaScript and AJAX and elsewhere in my website I use very little JavaScript and no AJAX. I will inspect AJAX-using solutions, but I would prefer staying with php.

Comment: if u want to get input from form into iframe then u can set 'action' attribute to iframe url  using ajax and referesh iframe

Comment: output buffering might be the answer?

Comment: @RamRaider: thanks for the tip, this was new to me. I tried it, but simple adding ob_start() just before and ob_end_flush() just after page body (for main page and iframe) didn't work. But I might have easily misunderstood something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this help? using php sessions. it can be done in JavaScript as well, but since you seem to be affectionate about php, here it is. Inside "index.php"

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["name"] = isset($_GET['myName'])?$_GET['myName']:"";
?>

<form name="MyForm" action="" method="GET">  
<input type="text" name="myName"/>
<input type="submit" />
</form>  
<iframe src="iframe.php" name="myIframe"></iframe>
```

then within "iframe.php"

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION["name"];
?>
```

Comment: Or $_POST instead of $_GET. This is very similar to what I already do. Session is superglobal, which may be an advantage or not, in my case it is. Originally I planned to place into session only derived variables produced in the iframe, but this looks safer than passing the variables as the part of the link, and worth emptying the values after their first use, as you do. +1; I'll wait for other answers before accepting it, for others' comments promise something more sophisticated.

Comment: not sure how they would achieve this with output buffering though, since the buffer is always emptied at the end of each script, but if they found a way i would love to see it. with javascript you could use contentWindow.parent.myVariable fairly simple way

Comment: No other answer, so I expect that the guy talking about output buffering though that this is just synchronization issue. It doesn't seem so. However, I accept this answer.